# dart regex matching and get some information from it

Tags: regex, dart

For practice, I decided to build something like a `Backbone` router. The user only needs to give the regex string like `r'^first/second/third/$'` and then hook that to a `View`.

For Example, suppose I have a `RegExp` like this :

```
String regexString = r'/api/\w+/\d+/';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(regexString);
View view = new View(); // a view class i made and suppose that this view is hooked to that url
```

And a `HttRequest` point to `/api/topic/1/` and that would match that regex, then i can rendered anything hook to that url.

The problem is, from the regex above, how do i know that `\w+` and `\d+` value is `topic` and `1`.

Care to give me some pointers anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to put the parts you want to extract into groups so you can extract them from the match. This is achieved by putting a part of the pattern inside parentheses.

```java
// added parentheses around \w+ and \d+ to get separate groups 
String regexString = r'/api/(\w+)/(\d+)/'; // not r'/api/\w+/\d+/' !!!
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(regexString);
var matches = regExp.allMatches("/api/topic/3/");

print("${matches.length}");       // => 1 - 1 instance of pattern found in string
var match = matches.elementAt(0); // => extract the first (and only) match
print("${match.group(0)}");       // => /api/topic/3/ - the whole match
print("${match.group(1)}");       // => topic  - first matched group
print("${match.group(2)}");       // => 3      - second matched group
```

however, the given regex would also match `"/api/topic/3/ /api/topic/4/"` as it is not anchored, and it would have 2 matches (`matches.length` would be 2) - one for each path, so you might want to use this instead:

```
String regexString = r'^/api/(\w+)/(\d+)/$';
```

This ensures that the regex is anchored exactly from beginning to the end of the string, and not just anywhere inside the string.

Comment: To anyone coming in from other languages - this unfortunate example starts and ends with /.../ - **BUT THE SLASHES ARE NOT PART OF THE REGEX**