# Dart: RegExp by example

Tags: regex, dart, string-matching

I'm trying to get my Dart web app to: (1) determine if a particular string matches a given regex, and (2) if it does, extract a group/segment out of the string.

Specifically, I want to make sure that a given string is of the following form:

```
http://myapp.example.com/#<string-of-1-or-more-chars>[?param1=1&param2=2]
```

Where `<string-of-1-or-more-chars>` is just that: any string of 1+ chars, and where the query string (`[?param1=1&param2=2]`) is **optional**.

So:

1. Decide if the string matches the regex; and if so
2. Extract the `<string-of-1-or-more-chars>` group/segment out of the string

Here's my best attempt:

```
String testURL = "http://myapp.example.com/#fizz?a=1";
String regex = "^http://myapp.example.com/#.+(\?)+\$";
RegExp regexp= new RegExp(regex);
Iterable<Match> matches = regexp.allMatches(regex);
String viewName = null;
if(matches.length == 0) {
    // testURL didn't match regex; throw error.
} else {
    // It matched, now extract "fizz" from testURL...
    viewName = ??? // (ex: matches.group(2)), etc.
}
```

In the above code, I know I'm using the RegExp API incorrectly (I'm not even using `testURL` anywhere), and on top of that, I have no clue how to use the RegExp API to extract (in this case) the "fizz" segment/group out of the URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
String regex = "^http://myapp.example.com/#([^?]+)";
```

And then grab: `matches.group(1)`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava (+1) - how do I use the [`RegExp`](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_core/RegExp.html) API to obtain a `matches` instance?

Comment: @CalifornianAcorn It's near the top in the documentation you linked to. `RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(\w+)"); String str = "Parse my string"; Iterable<Match> matches = exp.allMatches(str);`

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522918/dart-regex-matching-and-get-some-information-from-it

Answer (score 6):

The RegExp class comes with a convenience method for a single match:

```dart
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(r"^http://myapp.example.com/#([^?]+)");
var match = regExp.firstMatch("http://myapp.example.com/#fizz?a=1");
print(match[1]);
```

Note: I used anubhava's regular expression (yours was not escaping the ? correctly).

Note2: even though it's not necessary here, it is usually a good idea to use raw-strings for regular expressions since you don't need to escape $ and \ in them. Sometimes using triple-quote raw-strings are convenient too: `new RegExp(r"""some'weird"regexp\$""")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "^http://myapp.example.com/#([^?]+)";
```

Then:

```
var match = matches.elementAt(0);
print("${match.group(1)}"); // output : fizz
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError: Closure call with mismatched arguments: function 'elementAt' because no one knows what matches is