# Dart RegExp: single pass with multiple patterns?

Tags: regex, dart

If I search a string for matches to a regex which is the union of two or more sub-regexen, is there any way to determine which sub-regex matches without checking each of them individually?

For example, if I have the code:

```
var regExp = new RegExp('ab|cd');
var matches = regExp.allMatches('absolutely fabulous');
```

the search returns two matches - but is there a way for me to know which match corresponds to which sub-regex?

Comment: Use capturing group and capture both branches, but I don't use Dart so I don't know whether the capturing group is included in the result of allMatches.

Comment: amazing what an extra search term will get you with google :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522918/dart-regex-matching-and-get-some-information-from-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer thanks to searching for branches.

```
var regExp = new RegExp('(ab)|(cd)'); //brackets are significant
var matches = regExp.allMatches('absolutely fabulous');

var m1 = match.first;
print(m1.group(1)); // 'ab'
print(m1.group(2)); // null, since second term (cd) not matched here

var m2 = match.last;
print(m2.group(1)); // null, since first pattern not matched here
print(m2.group(2)): // 'ac'
```

Other useful info at 
[dart regex matching and get some information from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522918/dart-regex-matching-and-get-some-information-from-it)