# How to change this regular expression to detect number ranges?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I want to filter out a number range from a text.
For example in "Watch 1-3 episodes of your favorite show", I want to be able to detect 1-3.

Currently, I have this expression `\s\b[0-9 0-9]+[-]+[0-9 0-9]\b` but this only detects the range if there is text and/or a space before it and it also always includes the space in the match.

I want to be able to detect these ranges regardless of their position in the text.

What do I need to change in the expression to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dart regex matching and get some information from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16522918/dart-regex-matching-and-get-some-information-from-it)

Comment: Not exactly. The problem is not working with the match object but rather setting up the right regular expression to get the desired match object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex `[\d]+\-[\d]+` should work.